# Python Web Crawler, Can i do function calls from for loops?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I trying to code this web crawler so that it gets all the titles URL links and then goes to find all the chapters URL links, then from chapter links to find all the sections links and so on.

The problem is that, I see in this https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/blob/master/Python/27_workingsolution_python.py tutorial, the author was able to call the second function, before he defines it. Which is really confusing.

I tried the similar way, but got name "leveltwo" is not defined, as expected.
My question is, how to use links obtained from previous function to use it as parameter for second function and so.

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re


######################################Titles###############################
def levelone(url):
 r = requests.get(url)
 for links in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if links.has_attr('href'):
        if 'title' in links['href']:
          titlelinks = "http://law.justia.com" + links.get('href')
          # titlelinks = "\n" + str(titlelinks)  
          leveltwo(titlelinks) 
          # print (titlelinks)


base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2015/"
levelone(base_url)


########################################Chapters##########################
def leveltwo(item_url):
 r = requests.get(item_url)
 for sublinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sublinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'chapt' in sublinks['href']:
         chapterlinks = "http://law.justia.com" + sublinks.get('href')
         # chapterlinks = "\n" + str(chapterlinks)  

         levelthree(chapterlinks)
         # print (chapterlinks)

# leveltwo(titlelinks) ### I tried call the function right here, but titlelinks is not defined.

########################################Sections##########################
def levelthree(item2_url):
 r = requests.get(item2_url)
 for sectionlinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sectionlinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'section' in sectionlinks['href']:
         href = "http://law.justia.com" + sectionlinks.get('href')
         href = "\n" + str(href)
         print (href)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the function and then call.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re

########################################Sections##########################
def levelthree(item2_url):
 r = requests.get(item2_url)
 for sectionlinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sectionlinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'section' in sectionlinks['href']:
         href = "http://law.justia.com" + sectionlinks.get('href')
         href = "\n" + str(href)
         print (href)

########################################Chapters##########################
def leveltwo(item_url):
 r = requests.get(item_url)
 for sublinks in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
  if sublinks.has_attr('href'):
   if 'chapt' in sublinks['href']:
         chapterlinks = "http://law.justia.com" + sublinks.get('href')
         # chapterlinks = "\n" + str(chapterlinks)  

         levelthree(chapterlinks)
         # print (chapterlinks)

######################################Titles###############################
def levelone(url):
 r = requests.get(url)
 for links in BeautifulSoup((r.content),"html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if links.has_attr('href'):
        if 'title' in links['href']:
          titlelinks = "http://law.justia.com" + links.get('href')
          # titlelinks = "\n" + str(titlelinks)  
          leveltwo(titlelinks) 
          # print (titlelinks)

###########################################################################
base_url = "http://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2015/"
levelone(base_url)
```